# Wordpress page I am building is crashing my iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, wordpress, crash

I am just a weekend warrior when it comes to development, but I have managed to hack together a few wordpress sites in my time. I am having a very strange mobile problem on a specific dev one I am redesigning for kids - http://www.alphabetimals.com/wp/ - and which is running a recent wordpress and the qode bridge theme.

One specific page, which loads fine on my desktop, when viewed on my iPhone 7 (running the latest iOS) is freezing the Safari browser and not allowing me to navigate away. Once my screen sleeps, I cannot even restart my phone for the next 20-30 minutes.

I am loading a lot of sounds on the page, and I imagine its related to that, but I just don't know for sure. It has happened 3 times now and I am wary of trying to even view it again.

If anyone has ever run into this and can help I would greatly appreciate it. BEWARE though when checking on a mobile device. Here the page: http://alphabetimals.com/wp/dictionary/

Comment: Just wanted to add that this seems to work fine on android, tested on Firefox, Chrome, and Firefox Focus. I'd suggest testing it on another browser on your iPhone to see if it's the device or the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Check out this post about the mobile error you're getting:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted